# Part of the API is not working in NodeJS. How do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to build a REST API in NodeJS for an online-store. My code for the POST-request looks like this:

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const order = new Order({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        customer_name: req.body.order.customer_name,
        total_price: req.body.order.total_price,
        products: req.body.order.products,
    });
    order
    .save()
    .then(result => {
        req.body.order.products.forEach(value => {
            let availiableQuantity = value.available_quantity - value.ordered_quantity;
            Product.findOneAndUpdate({ id: value.id }, { available_quantity: availiableQuantity 
      })
     })
     res.status(201).json({
            message: "Successfully created product",
            createdProduct: {
                customer_name: result.customer_name,
                products: result.products,
        }
      });
    })
  .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
});
```

The issue that I'm having is that the code in **.then** block is not working when I'm trying to send this POST-request, even if I try to console.log something, it doesn't do anything, everything works except the code in **.then** block:

```
.then(result => {
        console.log('test')
        req.body.order.products.forEach(value => {
            let availiableQuantity = value.available_quantity - value.ordered_quantity;
            Product.findOneAndUpdate({ id: value.id }, { available_quantity: availiableQuantity 
      })
    })
```

Am I missing something out?

Comment: What does .save() do in your Order class?

Comment: @arina does `.save()` return a promise ? so it could chain the `then()` method ?

Comment: your answer is in the error block which you didnt catch.

Comment: @WiselyDCruizer, I do have a catch block in the code. I'm going to edit my question, sorry for that.

Comment: @Maielo yes, I think you're right

Comment: @tmdesigned .save() is a Mongoose method that saves the order to the database. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use async await instead of processing the next step with the then block.

```
 router.post('/',async (req, res) => {
  try{
   const order = new Order({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    customer_name: req.body.order.customer_name,
    total_price: req.body.order.total_price,
    products: req.body.order.products,
  });
  var result = await order.save();
  req.body.order.products.forEach(value => {
        let availiableQuantity = value.available_quantity - 
 value.ordered_quantity;
        Product.findOneAndUpdate({ id: value.id }, { 
 available_quantity: availiableQuantity 
 })
 res.status(201).json({
        message: "Successfully created product",
        createdProduct: {
            customer_name: result.customer_name,
            products: result.products,
    }
  });
  } catch(e) {
   res.status(500).json({
        message: "Bad request",
        error: e
  });
 }
})
```

Comment: I tried that and got the following  "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().", 
even though I do have a catch block, and the block after .save() is still not working

Comment: you can surround your code with try catch as i did in the edit.

Comment: Still doesn't work and got 500 error in response when using that.

Comment: what does your error say? that might just be the solution if any datatype or field is missing or is mismatched.